# Определить имя объекта.

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
var SomeGlobalObject = function(){
  this.prop1 = 1;
  this.prop2 = 2;
}
SomeGlobalObject.prototype.move(){
 /*
  вот здесь можно ли определить какой именно объект (obj1 или obj2) в настоящее время использует метод move? Я остановился на том, чтобы добавить этим объектам свойство name и по его значению их идентифицировать. Как по-другому можно определить имя объекта?
 */
}
var obj1 = new SomeGlobalObject();
var obj2 = new SomeGlobalObject();
obj1.move();
obj2.move();
```

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. Как все просто. Меня сбило с толку то, что console.log(this) выдает "SomeGlobalObject", а проверка ваша работает! 
Насчет вашего вопроса объясню - метод move содержит большое количество кода, общего для всех объектов. obj1,obj2,obj3 используют одинаковый код для своего движения, отличие лишь во взаимодействии с ДРУГИМИ объектами.
Для этого и нужно их различать. Преобразуйте в ответ ваш комментарий

Comment: @Deus: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая проверка должна подойти:

```
if (this === obj1) { ...
```

А вообще, объясните, для чего это вам. Не проще ли задать каждому из объектов свою функцию `move`?

---

Если у вас много общего кода, может быть, лучше сделать так:

```
SomeGlobalObject.prototype.move = function(){
 /* здесь код, бегущий в общем случае */
}

var obj1 = new SomeGlobalObject();
obj1.commonMove = obj1.move;
obj1.move = function() {
    // делаем то, что нужно только obj1
    this.commonMove(); // вызываем "общий" move
}
```

Или так:

```
SomeGlobalObject.prototype.commonMove = function(){
 /* здесь код, бегущий в общем случае */
}
SomeGlobalObject.prototype.move = function(){
 this.move(); // поведение по умолчанию
}

var obj1 = new SomeGlobalObject();
obj1.move = function() {
    // делаем то, что нужно только obj1
    this.commonMove(); // вызываем "общий" move
}
```